# Java generics return holder object from a generic method

Tags: java, generics

In the following:

```
public interface SomeInteface<A, B> {  
    public B doSomething(A a);  
}
```

I want to implement a version where the method `doSomething` returns the parameter `a` back.
I tried a `Holder` class;

```
class Holder<A> {  
     public A value;  
     public(A a){this.value = a;}  
}
```

and return `Holder`. However, I am not sure how to define an implementation class of `SomeInterface` so that I am able to do this.

The following does not even compile:

```
public class SomeImplementation<X> implements SomeInterface<T> {  

  private class Holder<A> {  
    public A value;  

    public class Holder<A>{  
      public A value;  
      public(A a){this.value = a;}  
    } 
  }   

  class Implementation<A, Holder<A>> implements SomeInterface<A, Holder<A>>{    
    public Holder<A> doSomething(A a){  
      //do stuff      
      return new Holder(a);  
    }   
  }      
}
```

What am I messing up here?

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: Why have you got a Holder inner class inside another Holder class? What are these classes adding to the code? Is there a reason you cannot just use the generic class?

Comment: @unholysampler:Eclipse shows red the question mark in `class Implementation<A, Holder<A>>`

Comment: @user846476:Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I asked a few things...let's keep it simple for the moment. Why is there a Holder class inside another Holder class?

Comment: @user846476:Don't I need to define the `Holder` to use it as a holder object so as to return the parameter encapsulated?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to specify `<A, Holder<A>>` as the generic type *parameters*; you specify the parameter names in the class declaration, the generic type *arguments* when you actually construct such an object. You'd need something like `class Implementation<A, B> implements SomeInterface<A, B>`, and then later declare a variable like `Implemenation<String, Holder<String>> myImpl = new Implementation<>();`

Comment: "I want to implement a version where the method doSomething returns the parameter a back." For what purpose?

Comment: Why can't you just do `public A doSomething(A a) { ... }` or `public Object doSomething(A a) { ... }` ?

Comment: You might want to avoid public fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be

```
class Implementation<A> implements SomeInteface<A, Holder<A>>{    
          public Holder<A> doSomething(A a){  
              //do stuff  
              return new Holder<A>(a);  
          }     

   }
```

In the classname you define the generic variables and their constraints. You don't need a Holder variable.

Comment: 1) you're using `Holder` as a raw type. it should be `new Holder<A>(a)` 2) "You could also do..." does not compile

Comment: Why use a `Holder` class at all?  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you make it so difficult.  You say

> I want to implement a version where the method `doSomething` returns the
>   parameter `a` back.

Well, you can do just that:

```
public class SomeImplementation<A> implements SomeInterface<A, A> {
    public A doSomething(A a) {
        // do stuff
        return a;
    }
}
```

No need for a Holder class.
The interface SomeInterface does not put any constraints on the type parameters, so there's no reason why they can't be the same.

Alternatively, you can allow your implementation to be parameterized with two different types A and B where A extends B (could be useful in some cases):

```
public class SomeImplementation<A extends B, B> implements SomeInterface<A, B> {
    public B doSomething(A a) {
        // do stuff
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: So `SomeInterface<A, A>` is the same as `SomeInterface<A, B>`?

Comment: It's the same interface with different type parameters.

Comment: So the fact that the original declaration was `SomeInteface<A,B>` does not impose any restriction to the implementing class declaration?Could be `Implementation<A,B>` or `Implementation<A,A>` or `Implementation<B,B>` or `Implementation<B,A>`?

Comment: Sure, you can even say `public class SomeImplementation<X, Y> implements SomeInterface<X, Y>` or `public class SomeImplementation implements SomeInterface<String, Long>`.  The A and B in the interface declaration are just names for type parameters.  Those names only make sense within that interface, just like names for method arguments don't mean anything outside the method.

Comment: Do you recommend a good resource for this?I keep get confused from time to time on these notations

Comment: Not really, but I wrote an article recently on using generics for database IDs in a data model.  That is a relatively simple case with some explanation which may provide some insight in the use of generics.  You can find it here: [Java data model with generic IDs](http://herman-b.hubpages.com/hub/Java-data-model-with-generic-IDs).  If anything is unclear or you have questions about the article contents you can leave a comment there.